# How to verify GD and Freetype support

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wordpress, packages

I'm running a server with ubuntu 9.10.

I'm trying to enable captcha support for our wordpress blog contact form and the instructions say that I'll need to "verify that PHP has GD support *and* Freetype support compiled in"

How can I verify this?

Additional information here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/323395

-M

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In command line:

GD Support:

> $ php -i | grep "GD "
>   (keep the space, it's necessary)

FreeType Support:

> $ php -i | grep "FreeType"

Answer (score 2):

Make a php file (like index.php) with the phpinfo() function and view it in the browser:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Also, I think you might just need to do the following to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

Answer (score 0):

From commandline:

```
php -m
```